# Symfony Doctrine DQL how to add SELECT in a SUM of a main SELECT

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

Actually, i would like to reproduce with Doctrine this regular SQL Query :

```
SELECT SUM(b.nb_places * (SELECT pricing FROM param p WHERE t.date BETWEEN p.from_date AND p.to_date)) as gains from booking b INNER JOIN tour t ON b.tour_id = t.id;
```

That compute total gains according prices between two dates.

I wrote this DQL in a Repository :

```
    public function allBooking() {
        $query = $this->manager->createQuery(
            'SELECT 
                 SUM(b.nbPlaces * SELECT p.pricing FROM \App\Entity\Param p WHERE t.date BETWEEN p.fromDate AND p.toDate)
        FROM App\Entity\Booking b JOIN b.tour t'
    );
    return $query->getResult();
}
```

But running this query, i got :

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 24: Error: Expected Literal, got 'SELECT' (500 Internal Server Error)
```

How do i acheive this query with DQL or using QueryBuilder ?

Thx for help

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about putting

```
SELECT p.pricing FROM \App\Entity\Param p WHERE t.date BETWEEN p.fromDate AND p.toDate
```

into additional brackets.

It should looks like this:

```
$query = $this->manager->createQuery(
    'SELECT SUM(b.nbPlaces * (SELECT p.pricing FROM \App\Entity\Param p WHERE t.date BETWEEN p.fromDate AND p.toDate))
    FROM App\Entity\Booking b JOIN b.tour t'
);
```

Comment: I'm affraid that is not working... Even with this update, i got the same error

Comment: According to some other investigations, it seems that those kind of query is not possible actuallay with Doctrine, have to fallback to raw query to acheive